# Group in group using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have array of objects:

```
[
{type: 'type1', user: 'user1', order: 'order-10', price: 100},
{type: 'type1', user: 'user1', order: 'order-20', price: 200},
{type: 'type2', user: 'user2', order: 'order-30', price: 300},
{type: 'type2', user: 'user1', order: 'order-40', price: 400}
]
```

Is it possible group it by *type* and inside *type group*, group by user, like this:

```
[
  {_id: 'type1', users: [
    {user: 'user1', orders: [{order: 'order-10', price: 100}, {order: 'order-20', price: 200}]}
  ]},
  {_id: 'type2', users: [
    {user: 'user1', orders: [{order: 'order-40', price: 400}]},
    {user: 'user2', orders: [{order: 'order-30', price: 300}]}
  ]}
]
```

I am trying to do as follows but so is not grouped by user:

```
db.aggregate([
        { $match: { date: { $gte: new Date(req.body.date.begin), $lt: end } } },
        { $lookup: { from: 'orders', localField: 'order', foreignField: '_id', as: 'order' } },
        { $unwind: "$order" },
        { $lookup: { from: 'clients', localField: 'user', foreignField: '_id', as: 'user' } },
        { $unwind: "$user" },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    type: '$type',
                    user: '$user.name',
                    order: '$order'
                },
                orders: {
                    $push: { order: '$order', price: '$price' }
                }
            }
        }, {
            $group: {
                _id: '$_id.type',
                users: { $push: { user: '$_id.user', orders: '$orders' } }
            }
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.aggregate([{
"$unwind: "$arrayOfObject" 
},{"$group":{
    "_id":"$type",
    "users":{
            "$addToSet":"$user",

            },
            "orders":{
                "$addToSet":"$orders"
                },
             "price":{
                 "$addToSet":"$price"
             }

    }}])
```

Comment: not exactly what i need. this solution will be return single arrays of users and orders. But thank you for try